# Problem with orthogonal traceless Hermitian matrices

Tags: quantum-process-tomography

In the compressive QPT method, the trace-preserving constraint of the process matrix is $\sum_{n, m} \chi_{n m} \Upsilon_m^{\dagger} \Upsilon_n=1$. In this paper:https://arxiv.org/abs/1404.2877,  as $\|\chi\|_{\operatorname{Tr}}=\operatorname{Tr}(\chi)$ being the object function, we must drop any equation that constrains the trace of the process matrix. They take an operator basis of traceless Hermitian matrices to ensure that there is only one equation relevant to the trace of the process matrix, which is dropped as a constraint. Thus define the estimator as follows:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\min . & \operatorname{Tr}(\chi) \\
\text { Subject to: } & \sum_{j, l}\left|f_{j l}-\operatorname{Tr}\left(D_{j l}^{\dagger} \chi\right)\right|^2 \leq \varepsilon \\
& \sum_{n, m \neq 1} \chi_{n m} \Upsilon_m^{\dagger} \Upsilon_n=0 \\
& \chi=\chi^{\dagger}, \chi \geq 0
\end{aligned}
$$
where now $\chi$ and $D_{j l}$ are represented in a basis with $\Upsilon_1=1$ and the elements $\Upsilon_{m \neq 1}$ are orthogonal traceless Hermitian matrices. The sum in the second constraint include all the terms except $n=m=1$. Finally, the estimated processmatrix $\hat{\chi}$ should be renormalized such that $\operatorname{Tr}(\hat{\chi} ) = d$.

I think there is something wrong, if the elements $\Upsilon_{m \neq 1}$ are orthogonal traceless Hermitian matrices, why $\sum_{n, m \neq 1} \chi_{n m} \Upsilon_m^{\dagger} \Upsilon_n=0$? For example, Pauli bases are orthogonal traceless Hermitian matrices, but $\operatorname{Tr}(P_m^{\dagger}P_n)=d\delta_{mn}$, as long as $m=n$, $P_m^{\dagger}P_m=I\ne 0$.

And if they want to ensure $\operatorname{Tr}(\chi)=d$,
we need orthogonal traceless Hermitian matrices that satisfies $\operatorname{Tr}(\Upsilon_m^{\dagger}\Upsilon_n)=\delta_{mn}$
. But Pauli bases satisfy $\operatorname{Tr}(\Upsilon_m^{\dagger}\Upsilon_n)=d\delta_{mn}$
, SVD basis, computational basis satisfy $\operatorname{Tr}(\Upsilon_m^{\dagger}\Upsilon_n)=\delta_{mn}$
, but they are not traceless Hermitian matrices, so I am confused.